# Including a log4j.properties file in my jar, but different properties file at execution time (optionally)

Tags: maven, cron, log4j

I want to include a log4j.properties file in my maven build, but be able to use a different properties file at execution time (using cron on unix)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate that a little bit more? Where is the relation to cron and Maven ?

Comment: there isn't one. i use maven in eclipse to build a jar file and transfer it to a unix machine. I need to be able to use a properties file in that execution environment instead of the one in the jar,i.e. suppose I'm running it in production and I need to go back to debug mode

Comment: So, why are you packaging a `log4j.properties` into the JAR to begin with?

Comment: because it will be running in a production environment. If a problem develops in production, I need to go back to the debug level.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to change properties per environment.
There are number approach to address this issue.

1. Create directory in each environment which will contain different files (log4j.properties in your example). Add these directories to your classpath in each environment.
2. Use filter ability + profile ability of maven in order to populate log4j.properties with correct values in the build time.
3. Use build server (Jenkins, for example) which essentially will make p.2.

Each of these approaches has it's own drawbacks. I am currently using a bit weired combination of 2&3 because Jenkins limitations.